# K8s Confluent Controlcenter pod lost from service and no error

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have installed CP-Kafka locally in K8s for Docker desktop. After a day or so the Contol Center remains in a wierd state. The service is visible:

```
$ kgsvc -l app=cp-control-center -o wide
NAME                             TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
officefriday-cp-control-center   NodePort   10.106.121.181   <none>        9021:30569/TCP   15h   app=cp-control-center,release=officefriday
```

The pod for the service is not there:

```
$ kgpo
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
curl                                               1/1     Running   0          12d
dnsutils                                           1/1     Running   0          14d
kafka-client                                       1/1     Running   0          40h
officefriday-cp-kafka-0                            2/2     Running   0          14h
officefriday-cp-kafka-1                            2/2     Running   0          14h
officefriday-cp-kafka-2                            2/2     Running   0          14h
officefriday-cp-kafka-connect-c77bd598c-x42tj      2/2     Running   1          15h
officefriday-cp-kafka-rest-6559b7588b-ld8wk        2/2     Running   0          15h
officefriday-cp-ksql-server-7fcdcdccd5-lwt2w       2/2     Running   0          15h
officefriday-cp-schema-registry-84855ff8f6-v6p28   2/2     Running   1          15h
officefriday-cp-zookeeper-0                        2/2     Running   0          15h
officefriday-cp-zookeeper-1                        2/2     Running   0          15h
officefriday-cp-zookeeper-2                        2/2     Running   0          15h
```

But the problem is that for K8s there is nothing wrong with it.

Now the CC service is still reachable:

[image]

I have restarted Docker and all the rest works apart from the missing pod.

How can one troubleshoot sth like that? Not much good hints out there.

Thnx!

Comment: Have you had a chance to check any relevant logs?

Comment: What would that be??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to say what might be the cause of this particular problem without any relevant logs or error messages. However, there are some recommended steps that should be taken in order to debug this and any similar problem in the future.

According to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/) you should start from:

- [Debugging Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/#debugging-pods)
- [Debugging Replication Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/#debugging-replication-controllers)
- [Debugging Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/#debugging-services)

Also, it is strongly suggested to [examine Pod logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#examine-pod-logs) if possible.

I hope this helps to solve your issue. Please let me know what are your findings so I could help further if needed.